# select category after link remove special characters?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page to show some people's name, so user can click and see their related posts.

The problem is people with `'` or `.` in the name or any other special character.

To create the URL I need to remove this characters:

```
Marie E.A 
Josh O'Reilly
```

php to create the link:

```
$categorialink = strtolower($categoria);
$categorialink = str_replace(' ', '_', $categorialink);
$categorialink = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\_-]/', '', $categorialink);
```

will become:

```
www.mypage.com/person/marie_ea
www.mypage.com/person/josh_oreilly
```

the problem is to get this values from mysql, Mysql record the name as it is (Marie E.A) and I can't go back to the original person's name.
mysql LIKE could help, but can open another person page by select something similar eg: Marie E.B instead of Marie E.A.

```
$categoryp = $_GET['categoria'];
$category = str_replace("_", " ", $categoryp);
SELECT id, categoria FROM categoria where categoria = 'marie ea' limit 1 //$category value - return nothing
```

how to solve this?

Comment: Smarter to use urlencode ()

Answer (score 1):

Just use `urlencode ()` . That will translate string by only replacing letters, not deleting them. Later if You need to get previous name, just use `rawurldecode()` .